# Dont receive intent from other application

Tags: android, onactivityresult

In my first app I run the second one with the following code:

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent();
            myIntent.setClassName("com.XXX.XXX", "com.XXX.XXX.Main");
            myIntent.putExtra("date", date);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
```

In App B I send some extras back to App B:

```
Intent resultIntent = getIntent();
        resultIntent.putExtra("extra", value);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
        finish();
```

In App A I want to get the value extra:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                String street = data.getStringExtra("extra");
            }
        }
}
```

When I run it, `resultCode` is always 0 (`RESULT_CANCELED`) and data is null in `onActivityResult`. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: A result code specified by the second activity. This is either `RESULT_OK` if the operation was successful or `RESULT_CANCELED` if the user backed out or the operation failed for some reason. Double check your logic inside B is correct, as what you are posting in the question is just dummy logic, it is hard to tell what is wrong.

Comment: yes I always get RESULT_CANCELED, but why if I just run the code from above

Answer (score 0):

**Try changing this**

```
Intent resultIntent = getIntent();

setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
```

**To this**

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();

setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` from below code.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
        //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                String street = data.getStringExtra("extra");
            }
        }
}
```